# Want to start service in android and run untill app uninstalled

Tags: android, service, timer, timestamp, sharedpreferences

I have an android app in which i execute some task every 24 hours (a day).
For that I have registered a service and it runs first time and I have also used `Timer` class in it to execute my method after a fix interval.
It works perfect for first time but when I start the app next time, service starts from scratch and timer is reinitialized.I tried to handle this with shared preferences but no success.

Can you suggest me some ways to do some task in my app after exactly 24 hours until user deletes app.

Comment: check [Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try out with Alarm Manager. It wakes your service at the time you want.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html